# Working with Authorize.net's api for eChecks

Tags: php, authorize.net

I developing a way for people to pay with an echeck and have the option to autopay (subscription). I have the e-check working and going into my sandbox account but now how do I make it so that they can now cancel that echeck subscription? I been searching around the web now and can't seem to find any solid examples. I have already successfully implemented the credit card subscriptions and cancel features and need the same for eCheck. Does anyone have any experience with this? Seems like authorize.net's documentation is lacking information to implement this with echecks.

Comment: Are you using Recurring Billing (ARB) for your subscriptions?  http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing

Comment: Yes, so should it be the same as credit cards ARB right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Recurring Billing for subscriptions, it's the same call to cancel regardless of the payment type (card or check).  http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing-cancel-a-subscription